# How do I control the tabbing order of input tags in html?

Tags: html, tabindex

I have the following html input fields, two are for user input one to submit the responses.

```html
<div>
  <select id="netcall" class="" name="netcall" onchange="chngDFLTS()">
    <option value="0" selected>Select One</option>
    <option value="1" selected>Select Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="cs1" type="text" value="" tabindex=1 />
  <input id="Fname" type="text" value="" tabindex=2 />
  <input id="ckin1" type="submit" value="Check In" tabindex=3 />
</div>
```

If I understand http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp correctly then the tab sequence should be 1 to 2 to 3. Tabbing from CS1 to Fname works every time, but the next tab takes me to a select field which does not even have a tabindex value and is not even in the same div tag. Additionally no amount of further tabbing ever takes me to the ckin1, submit input tag.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: What select element? There isn't one in your example. You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: I've adjusted the original question.

Comment: pasted your code on jsfiddle, can't reproduce the problem using chrome.

Comment: wlin you are correct it seems to work in Chrome. My default it Safari. I wonder how I can get around that?